# NumPy Scipy optimization

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I have an optimization issue and I'm not sure if I can improve the overall speed of my function.

The function `draw_w` is my actual implementation that gives me the right update for my vector `w`. You can see that the code is running for 1000 iterations in 9s.
I had a first implementation (`draw_w_fw`) that was quiet good because, well-vectorized, that is an order of magnitude quicker by 0.8s. Unfortunately, this implementation is wrong because the `cache[0]` is not updated correctly.

I would like to know if someone knows a way to speed up `draw_w` from what I've wrote.

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import numpy as np
import timeit


def draw_w(X, w, cache):

    X = X.tocsr()

    for i in xrange(w.shape[0]):
        x_li = X.getrow(i)
        Y = w[i] * x_li
        Y.data -= np.take(cache[0], Y.indices) 
        h = x_li.multiply(-Y)

        w_mean = h.sum()
        w_sigma_sqr = (x_li.multiply(x_li)).sum() 

        w_sigma_sqr = 1.0 / w_sigma_sqr
        w_mean = - w_sigma_sqr * w_mean

        # update w:
        w_old = np.copy(w[i])

        if np.isinf(w[i]):
            w[i] = 0
        elif np.isnan(w[i]):
            w[i] = 0
        else:
            w[i] = w_mean

        # update error:
        cache[0] -= (w_old - w[i]) * x_li

    #print 'draw_w', w
    #True result w [ 2.34125626  2.37726446  4.00792293  3.71059779  4.00792293  0.11100713
    # -0.28899287 -0.04393113  0.21429929]

####################


def draw_w_fw(X, w, cache):

    x_li = X.tocsr()
    nnz_per_row = np.diff(x_li.indptr)
    Y = sps.csr_matrix((x_li.data * np.repeat(w, nnz_per_row), x_li.indices, x_li.indptr), shape=x_li.shape)
    Y.data -= np.take(cache[0], Y.indices)   #not good because cache[0] is updated...
    h = x_li.multiply(-Y)

    w_mean = np.asarray(h.sum(axis=1).transpose())[0]
    w_sigma_sqr = np.asarray(( x_li.multiply(x_li) ).sum(axis=1).transpose())[0]

    w_sigma_sqr = 1.0 / w_sigma_sqr
    w_mean = - w_sigma_sqr * w_mean

    # update w:
    w_old = np.copy(w)

    w[~np.isnan(w) & ~np.isinf(w)] = w_mean[~np.isnan(w) & ~np.isinf(w)]

    w[np.isinf(w)] = 0.0
    w[np.isnan(w)] = 0.0

    # update error:
    cache[0] -= (w_old - w) * x_li

    #print 'draw_w_fw', w

##########################


def test():

    data = [ 1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]
    cols = [ 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14]
    rows = [0,5,1,5,2,5,3,5,4,5,0,6,1,6,2,6,3,6,4,6,1,7,3,7,0,8,2,8,4,8]

    X = sps.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape = (9,15))
    X = X.tocsr()

    w = np.array([ 0.16243454, -0.06117564, -0.05281718, -0.10729686,  0.08654076, -0.23015387,  0.17448118, -0.07612069,  0.03190391])

    cache = np.zeros((2, 15))
    cache[0] =  np.asarray([-5.06771933, -5.29132951, -4.28297104, -1.33745073, -2.14361311, -0.66308429,
     -0.88669446, -2.878336,  -4.93281569, -4.73897806, -1.13729633, -5.18341755,
     -0.80566155, -5.02091327, -4.88155533])
    #draw_w(X, w, cache)
    draw_w_fw(X, w, cache)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1000))
    #draw_w:    9.26 for 1000 iterations
    #draw_w_fw: 0.80 for 1000 iterations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before streamlining the code, it almost always pays off to streamline the math. The `h` you calculate is the dot product of two vectors, `X[i]` and `Y[i] = cache[0] - w[i]*X[i]`, so we can rewrite it as

```
h = X[i].cache[0] - w[i]*X[i].X[i]
```

When you go on to calculate `w_mean`, you are actually negating `h` and then dividing it by a number that turns out to be `X[i].X[i]`, so you can calculate `w_mean` as

```
w_mean = w[i] - X[i].cache[0] / X[i].X[i]
```

Setting aside the `np.isnan` and `np.isinf` checks you are doing, you then update `cache[0]` with a value where `w[i]` cancels out, and you are basically doing:

```
cache[0] -= X[i] * (X[i].cache[0] / X[i].X[i])
```

Putting it all together into a single function, I got this very compact code:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def draw_w_bis(X, w, cache):
    X = X.tocsr()
    x_rows_sqr = np.add.reduceat(X.data*X.data, X.indptr[:-1])
    rows, cols = X.shape
    row_start_stop = as_strided(X.indptr, shape=(rows, 2),
                                strides=2*X.indptr.strides)
    for row, (start, stop) in enumerate(row_start_stop):
        data = X.data[start:stop]
        cols = X.indices[start:stop]
        delta = np.dot(data, cache[0, cols]) / x_rows_sqr[row]
        w[row] -= delta
        cache[0, cols] -= delta * data
```

If you are not comfortable with calling `as_strided` you could replace the definition of `row_start_stop` with:

```
row_start_stop = np.column_stack((X.indptr[:-1], X.indptr[1:]))
```

On my system your test code runs the 1000 iterations over an order of magnitude faster (6 sec vs. 0.4 sec) which seems to be what you were after. There still is a for loop in there, so if you are going to run this on large arrays, it is still going to be slow, and you may want to consider using things like Cython.

Comment: There are 2 parts to your speedup. 1) the last 3 lines that streamline the inner loop. 2) iteration using `as_strided(X.indptr...)`.  The streamlining saves about 20% when plugged into my fastest pure python version.  Using `strided` instead of `lil` in my `cython` code drops the time from `0.43` to `0.41`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of `draw_w`, working with the data for one row.

```
def draw_np(Xdata, Xindices, w, cache):
    # Xdata, Xindices are from a csr row
    # w scalar
    # cache vector
    Ydata = w * Xdata
    Ydata -=  np.take(cache, Xindices)
    h = - Xdata * Ydata
    w_mean = h.sum()
    w_sigma_sqr = (Xdata*Xdata).sum()
    w_mean = - w_mean / w_sigma_sqr
    cache[Xindices] -= (w - w_mean) * Xdata
    return  w_mean

for i in xrange(w.size):
    xli = X.getrow(i)
    w[i] = draw_np(xli.data, xli.indices , w[i], cache[0])
```

Compared to the 9 sec for `draw_w`, this is 1.6 sec. I've omitted the `isInf` and `isNan` tests (which should apply to `w_mean`), but I don't think that's significant.  My guess is the speed comes from working with the simpler `numpy` data vectors rather than the full `sparse` matrix.

I wrote this simplified Python version as a step toward a faster (hopefully) `cython` function:

```
def draw_cy(Xdata, Xindices, w, cache):
    cdef double w_mean
    cdef double w_sigma_sqr
    cdef double ydata
    cdef double value
    cdef int size
    cdef int ind
    size = Xdata.shape[0]
    w_mean = 0.0
    w_sigma_sqr = 0.0
    for i in range(size):
        value = Xdata[i]
        ind = Xindices[i]
        ydata = w * value
        ydata -= cache[ind]
        ydata = - value * ydata
        w_mean += ydata
        w_sigma_sqr += value * value
    w_mean = - w_mean / w_sigma_sqr
    for i in range(size):
        value = Xdata[i]
        ind = Xindices[i]
        cache[ind] -= (w - w_mean) * value
    return  w_mean

# requires a compile to .c and .so and import

for i in xrange(w.size):
    xli = X.getrow(i)
    w[i] = draw_cy(xli.data, xli.indices , w[i], cache[0])
```

This times at 1.1 sec, nearly as good as the fully vectorized (but erroneous) `draw_w_fw`.  But the speedup compared to `draw_np` isn't that great.

---

more on timings.  I pulled out various pieces from this last iteration, and deduced that

```
bare loop (pass) took 0.27 sec  (that includes setup)
9 calls to getrow took 0.64 sec
9 calls to draw_cy took 0.10 sec
9 calls to draw_np took 0.60 sec
```

It's significant that the `X.getrow()` took as long as the barebones numpy `draw_np` calculation.  My impression is that `scipy.sparse` is a convenient way of setting up sparse matricies, and a good way of doing large linear algebra problems (e.g. FEM), but it is not a fast way of doing general matrix operations.

I tried a dense `numpy` iterator:

```
Xa = X.A
for i in xrange(w.size):
    x1 = Xa[i,:]; nz = x1.nonzero()[0]; x1=x1[nz]
    w[i] = cy.draw_cy(x1, nz, w[i], cache[0])
```

The time for this is 0.62 sec., 0.5 less than the `getrow` version.  Using `draw_np` gives a similar time savings.

In other words, if `X` isn't so large that you can't store it as a dense array, it might be faster to skip the `sparse` module entirely.  But I haven't explored how these timings vary with the size of `X` and `w`.

---

`lil` iteration is even a bit faster, since its `data` and `rows` are matching lists:

```
Xl = X.tolil()
for i, (xd, xr) in enumerate(zip(Xl.data, Xl.rows)):
    #w[i] = cy.draw_cy(np.array(xd), xr, w[i], cache[0])
    w[i] = cpy.draw_py(np.array(xd), xr , w[i], cache[0])
```

If the `X.data` are all `1` (as in the test case), the calculations can be simplified even more (only `X.rows` has useful information).

Comment: I tested it on my computer and don't have the same speed up. I have 3.75 so it's definitely an improve but still too slow for what I need. I'm impress by the speedup for so little change. I'll definitely take a look at Cython and give you the bounty if nobody else answer.

Comment: Further testing shows that `X.getrow()` takes a nontrivial amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

At least with your test `X`, `draw_x_fw` works with 2 calls.  The rows of `X` fall into two groups, each with a unique set of columns.  I don't know if that's a structural part of the problem, or just a random characteristic your chosen test.

```
    n = 5
    draw_w_fw(X[:n,:], w[:n], cache) # n items
    draw_w_fw(X[n:,:], w[n:], cache)
```

With simple slicing like this, `w[:n]` is a view, so changes to `w` inside the function are visible outside it.  If we do a more general row selection, we have to explicitly set the new `w` values.

Comment: This part is a coincidence. On real dataset, I can't just find some slicing like that but good point.